# C# - How to know if object is a derivative of ICollection

Tags: c#, reflection, collections

I have a generic list:

```
IList<T> myobj = new List<T>();
```

how to check if `myobj` is a generic list (aka. `IList<T>`)?

I've tried, with no success:

```
if(myobj.GetType().IsGenericType && myobj is IList) //second exp is never true
```

I don't want to know the Type of T at this moment, i just want to know if `myobj` is a list.

---EDIT---------------------

'myobj' was being null all the time, this caused it to fail all checks. Sorry, my bad. Turns out the solutions described in my questions (which are similar to some of your answers) works just fine. I haven't tried the other answers though.

I was doing the following:

```
PropertyType propInf = ...
var myobj = propInf.GetValue(parentobj,null);//was always null
```

Comment: `IList` is a non-generic interface defined separately from `IList<T>`.

Comment: Are `myObj` and `value` intended to be the same reference?  `List<T>` does inherit `IList`, so the second expression should evaluate to true for `myObj`.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982487/testing-if-object-is-of-generic-type-in-c-sharp

Comment: 'myobj' was being null all the time, this caused it to fail all checks. Sorry, my bad. Turns out the solutions described in my questions (which are similar to some of your answers) works just fine. I haven't tried the other answers though.

Comment: @PsychoDad this is not quite the same question as the one you linked to.  The type the OP wants to check for is an interface type rather than the class type, so the solution is slightly different.

Comment: @phoog True but the principal is the same, just change to IList instead of List.

Comment: But you need another step, because `myobj.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>)` will evaluate to false.  `GetType()` returns (e.g.) the type `List<string>`; GetGenericTypeDefinition()` returns the type `List<>` and `List<>` is not equal to `IList<>` -- it implements it, but it's not equal to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `(myObj is IList)`:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> foo = new List<int>();
        bool b = foo is IList;  // true
    }
```

Most of the generic collection interfaces in .NET have non-generic counterparts (for example `IList` and `IList<T>`)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer is getting upvotes: the OP did try `(myobj is IList)` and got false when he expected true; that's why he posted the question.

Comment: I think the OP has edited the question (and apparently accepted this answer)

Comment: Hm, I looked at the edit history, and the original version included the 'myObj is IList' check.  Of course, as the poster indicates in an edit, the reason it was failing is that myObj was null.

Answer (score 2):

```
typeof(IList<>).IsAssignableFrom(myobj.GetType())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid multiple type checks like this:

```
var list = myObj as IList;
if (list != null)
{
    //do something with it
}
```

The similar code using `is` requires two type checks, one for the `is` operator and one for the cast:

```
if (myObj is IList)
{
    var list = (IList)myObj;
    //do something with it
}
```

Though I am perplexed as to why your `myobj is IList` is always false.  It should be true.  Perhaps you have a class that implements `IList<T>` but not `IList`.  `IList<T>` does not inherit from `IList`.

If you really want to know whether the object implements `IList<T>`, try this

```
foreach (var interfaceType in myobj.GetType().GetInterfaces())
    if (interfaceType.IsGenericType)
        if (interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>))
            return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the "is" operator isn't working then you could use [`Type.IsAssignableFrom()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx):

```
typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 typeof(IList<T>).IsAssignableFrom(myobj.GetType())
```

or

```
 myObj is IList<T>
```

The reason your code is failing as that you are using non-generic list IList, instead of the generic one IList. Those are two different types in C#.

Further more, to get all interfaces implemented by your object, you can use reflection:

```
 myObj.GetType().GetInterfaces();
```