# How to determine if class inherits Dictionary<,>

Tags: c#, reflection

I have

```
public class SerializableDictionary<TKey, TValue>
    : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, IXmlSerializable
```

And I want to check if an object is SerializeableDictionary (of any generic types).

For that I tried:

```
type == typeof(SerializableDictionary<,>)
or type.isSubclass()
or typeof(SerializableDictionary<,>).isAssigneableFrom(type)
```

nothing works.
How can I tell if the type is SerializableDictionary or any type?

tnx!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing if object is of generic type in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982487/testing-if-object-is-of-generic-type-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var obj = new List<int>(); // new SerializableDictionary<string, int>();
var type = obj.GetType();

var dictType = typeof(SerializableDictionary<,>);
bool b = type.IsGenericType && 
         dictType.GetGenericArguments().Length == type.GetGenericArguments().Length &&
         type == dictType.MakeGenericType(type.GetGenericArguments());
```

Comment: `MakeGenericType` will throw an exception if the number of type arguments passed in doesn't match.  So if `obj` was say a `List<string>` this would throw instead of returning `false`.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably create an interface `ISerializableDictionary` and let `SerializableDictionary<TKey, TValue>` inherit from that.

```
public interface ISerializableDictionary : IDictionary
{
}

public class SerializableDictionary<TKey, TValue>
    : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, IXmlSerializable, ISerializableDictionary
```

Then just:

```
var res = dic is ISerializableDictionary;
```

Comment: @Himberjack Can you be more specific?