# Detect that object is any kind of HashSet<T>?

Tags: c#

Effectively I want to do something like:

`if( obj is HashSet )`

...without the generic `<T>` parameter, so *any kind* of `HashSet`.

I can give more context if necessary, except it would be a bit of a can of worms!

Comment: Obviously replace `List<>` with `HashSet<>`

Comment: @Liam The OP has no `List` to replace...

Comment: As in, in the [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/982495/542251) @Servy

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I had no idea you could do `List<>` or `HashSet<>`!