# C# Generic type comparison

Tags: c#, generics

I have this code:

```
public class myList<T> where T : struct
{
    public int number { get; set; }
}

public class TypeTest
{
    public static int GetNumber(object x)
    {
        //  if (x.GetType() == typeof(myList<>)) // this works BUT I want to use is
        if (x is myList<>) // how is the correct syntax for this?
        {
            int result = ((myList<>)x).numb; //does not compile
            return result;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

But some generic syntax issues.

Question: What is the correct Syntax for this?

Comment: `x.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(myList<>)`?

Comment: You can't cast to an open generic type, however.  It isn't clear *why* this class is generic or what you hope to gain by making it generic.

Comment: you cannot assure the object to be of generic type. so instead of `if(x is myList<>)` use `if(x.GetType().IsGenericType && typeof(MyList<>) == x.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition())`

Answer (score 4):

It would be nice to re-declare your method as a generic one:

```
public static T GetNumber<T>(myList<T> myList) where T : struct
```

Doing so you would avoid any casts and the method's body would become one-liner as below:

```
return myList?.numb ?? 0;
```

Comment: I can't change the method definition just the content of the method `(object x)`

Comment: @Dr.Snail: A flawed method will yield a flawed algorithm. You're never going to get a _good_ answer using this flawed approach. It is flawed for many reasons, most notably opening the door to runtime exceptions. If someone with a higher paygrade is forcing you to use this method signature, then they should bear the responsibility of their decision.

Comment: @Dr.Snail If that's the case, please follow CodeCaster's solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the object is of your open generic type as explained in [Testing if object is of generic type in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982487/testing-if-object-is-of-generic-type-in-c-sharp), and then get the property named "number" from the actual type:

```
var typeOfX = x.GetType();
if (typeOfX.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(myList<>))
{
    var numberProperty = typeOfX.GetProperty("number");

    var propertyValue = numberProperty.GetValue(x);

    return (int)propertyValue;
}
```

Do note that this code lacks any error handling, such as missing property or a property not of the expected type. That's the price you pay for being forced to use reflection.

Comment: You could have an one-liner: `int result = (int)((dynamic)x).number`.

Comment: Agreed, but that's adding even more overhead and potential errors for working around a design flaw.