# How do I test if an IHttpActionResult returns OkNegotiatedContentType<anonymous>?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics

Trying to find a clean way of assert this.

Controller method returns:

```
        return Ok(new
        {
           Prop = "123", // many props, handle it
        });
```

Before, I was using a string, so I did:

`Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(OkNegotiatedContentResult<string>));`

However now it's an anonymous object, I can't figure out how to do the same test as above.

There are some ways to work out if a type *is* an anonymous type that I've found on here, but not to see if something is a type of anonymous.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing if object is of generic type in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982487/testing-if-object-is-of-generic-type-in-c-sharp)

Comment: But why not just create a class instead of going anonymous?

Comment: @canton7 Sure does, that's exactly what I needed! Many thanks.