# C# Checking if object is Span<T>

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, clr, cil

Currently I am writing C# code under .NET Core 3.1 for checking if the current type (I use `Mono.Cecil`, but `System.Reflection` might suit better) is a `Span` type. Having found info about how to check if the type is [generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982487/testing-if-object-is-of-generic-type-in-c-sharp), I wrote some dummy code for such sort of check:

```
        unsafe
        {
            IntPtr unmanagedHandle = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(16);
            Span<byte> unmanaged = new Span<byte>(unmanagedHandle.ToPointer(), 16);
            if (unmanaged is object)
                if ((unmanaged as object).GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Span<>))
                    Console.WriteLine("Span!");
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmanagedHandle);
        }
```

Despite the official MSDN docs say that `Span<>` [IS an object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=netcore-3.1), when compiling, I get stuck with a warning and an error: CS0184 warns that `"unmanaged" is never of the "object"` type, and CS0039 tells that `"System.Span<byte>" cannot be converted to "object" via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion`. At leasts, the docs point out that `Span<>` is not a usual `object` really.

Is there any other way (having only one dependency `Mono.Cecil`) to determine whether some `object` (or another underlying piece of data, referred to by the `IntPtr`, at least) is a Span-derived?

Comment: Can you try casing with `as`? Like: `if (unmanaged as Span != null)`

Comment: You should never be able to get into a situation where a reference to an unknown type is in fact a `Span<>`, as you're finding out. So the simple way to simplify your code is to just answer `false`.

Comment: @Jonathan, using "as" with `Span`, in any form, brings the same CS0039 error

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, unless you need to enumerate all types you meet in code - for any Reflection-involving task (like assembly obfuscation or protection)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, I know it is not actually fine, but I have to deal with the name checking approach. Due to the semi-object (whatever) nature of the `System.Span<T>` class, we cannot compare `Span` to any object, but we can use comparation like `typeof(System.Span<byte>)`. This can only be useful if we always do know preliminary, how (i.e., with which `T`) `Span` can be instantiated, but this is NOT my case actually. There seem to be no reliable mechanisms to distinguish `Span`, besides name checking. So that, checking the type name seems to be the only suitable approach.

Using `Mono.Cecil`, I used for a `TypeReference` the following condition:

```
bool IsSpanType(TypeReference type) {
    return type.FullName.StartsWith("System.Span`1");
}
```

As you see, there is no happy-end, but it works fine enough though. And I cannot see any reasons to perform any more paranoid checks (like checking such properties of `TypeReference` like `Scope`, `ElementType`, or whatever else).

Comment: Can you clarify, do you want to test if some object instance is of type `Span<...>` or do you want to test if an object instance of type `Type`/`TypeReference` represents a `Span<...>` type?

Comment: @thehennyy, `TypeReference`s only

Comment: What's wrong with `type.IsGenericType && typeof(Span<>).Equals(type.GetGenericTypeDefinition())`? Your question indicated that you are fine with comparing instances of `System.Type`.

Answer (score 2):

`Span<T>` is a `ref` (stack-only) struct, which means it can't be saved into a variable of type `object`, because it can't be boxed.

From the `Span<T>` [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=netcore-3.1) (emphasis mine):

> Span is a **ref struct** that is allocated on the stack rather than on the managed heap. Ref struct types have a number of restrictions to ensure that they cannot be promoted to the managed heap, including that **they can't be boxed, they can't be assigned to variables of type Object** [...]

So when you have a variable or parameter `object obj`, you know that `obj` will never be a `Span<T>`, because `obj` always points to an object on the heap (for example when you store an integer in `obj`, it will be automatically boxed into a heap object).

**But** it might be a `Memory<T>`, which is the non-stack-only (normal struct) equivalent of `Span<T>`.