# C# Reflections: How to get type of a generic object

Tags: c#, generics, reflections

Lets say I have the following class

```csahrp
public class MyClass<T>
{
  public Method(T input)
  {
    //performs logic with input
  }
}
```

I would like to store the MyClass type in a value like

```csharp
Type classType = typeof(MyClass);
```

But since MyClass is a generic class, I cannot perform that operation without declaring a generic like `typeof(MyClass<AnotherClass>)`.

Is there a way to make this work?

I wrote somethig like

```csharp
private void PerformLogic(Type inputType)
{
      MethodInfo getTypeMethod = typeof(this).GetMethod("GetType");
      getTypeMethod = getTypeMethod.MakeGenericMethod(inputType);
      Type result = (Type)getTypeMethod.Invoke(default, default);
      
      // ...
}

private static Type GetType<T>()
    where T : class
{
    Type type = typeof(MyClass<T>);
    return type;
}
```

But I feel like there is a cleaner way to do this without creating an extra method with "0 references"

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982487/testing-if-object-is-of-generic-type-in-c-sharp/982495#982495) may be helpful if you already have a `Type` instance for a close-constructed type and want to know what the open generic type is.

Comment: By "the MyClass type," do you mean the type argument "T"? Or do you mean the constructed generic type "MyClass<T>"?

Comment: madreflection that really helped. 
This is what I needed
`Type closedType = typeof(MyClass<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);`

Comment: You might also like to keep https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition?view=net-5.0 to hand, for the `GetGenericTypeDefinition` method.

Answer (score 0):

At "performs logic with input", you can write:

- `typeof(T)` to examine the type information of the type argument `T`
- `typeof(MyClass<>)` to examine the `MyClass<>` type as a generic type definition
- `typeof(MyClass<T>)` to examine the closed generic type of `MyClass<T>`.